# Removing odd symbols from web scraped text

Tags: php, json

There is content that is web scraped and stored in a JSON string retrieved using the script

```
$response = response($jsonData)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

I then use the following scripts to extract the JSON content and decode the string

```
    $jsonData = $response->getContent();
    $decodedData = json_decode($jsonData);
```

The problem is the text is the string has odd text like \u2019 and \u2018 which seem to be replacing some punctuation marks. What are these and how can I remove them?

Comment: They are Unicode encodings of the quote mark characters. It's unclear, are those present in the raw JSON text before it's decoded, or in the decoded strings, or both? Your description was a bit vague about that.

Comment: `json_decode` should take `\u2019 and \u2018` and give you `â and â`. There's a chance there's triple escape characters happening, i.e. `\\\u2019 and \\\u2018`. Check here: https://3v4l.org/AVQ4O

Comment: Hi @ADyson, yes they are present in the raw JSON text before the decode

Comment: Ok well as per the example above, they should disappear when you decode it. is that not happening? Perhaps it's because of some escaping issue, like in Jacob's example? If that doesn't help, please provide us a [mre] of the issue including sample JSON which you are struggling to decode.